# What are CGroup Slices Used For

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, process, cgroups

Just been paying attention to systemctl status' branching structure. I realized I was making up stories to explain why it looked like that but had no clue of what it meant. I can't find much info on slices.

My story is that they are sliced off into isolation. And add security from reading the wrong address... that they probably constantly use the same virtually sliced addys.

[image: systemd branch view]

Can you give me some insight into what that illustration means from the OS perspective? Or your perspective...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Slices are a systemd concept.  Systemd uses cgroups for low level implementation of slices.   This is unrelated to memory protection.  All processes have their own isolated memory without slices.

cgroups is part of the low level implementation of the container system, which allows putting limits on the resources a group of processes can use, allowing a hard division of system resources.  This is a resource allocation issue, not a memory sharing issue, and being in the same slice does not cause memory to be shared between processes.

The systemd slice system (with the help of services and scopes) allows grouping related processes together (for instance, a user's session or a system service composed of multiple processes).  Each slice can have maximum cpu and memory resources allocated to it, which can prevent a single slice from causing a denial of service attack on other slices by running the system out of resources.  But also, it allows grouping processes together so that they can all be killed at once, for instance, when a user logs out (this is not enabled by default).

The man page for `systemd.slice` details this.  The man page for `systemd.resource-control` lists the resources that can be limited within a slice.

Answer (score 1):

The hypothetical proposition “I want to make use of kernel cgroups, how do I do this in the new world order?” is used to explain how scope needs to be managed, and how slices play a role in this for systemd: [The New Control Group Interfaces](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/ControlGroupInterface/)

It highlights the ability to define constraints to members of a slice that trump the predefined allowances granted the the member’s author. Kind of like a cool handcuff feature.